# Please help with finding binomial coefficient in the following expression

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to find the coefficient of $x^{2m}$ from the both sides of the following equality:

$$ \frac{(1-x^2)^n}{(1-x)^n} = (1+x)^n $$

For the right side of equality I've found it as follow:

$$ [x^{2m}] (1+x)^n=\binom{n}{2m} $$

With the left side of equation I have a problem:
$$ [x^{2m}] (1-x^2)^n(1-x)^{-n}=? $$

Also, according to previous computations of coefficient, is needed to build the following equality of the sums of binomial-coefficients:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^? ??=\binom{n}{2m} $$

Can some one please explain how to get it?

For example if given that $n=5$ and $m=2$:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k}{k} = \binom{n}{2m}$$

$$ \sum_{k=0}^5 \binom{k}{k} = \binom{5}{4}$$

$$ \binom{0}{0} + \binom{1}{1} + \binom{2}{2} + \binom{3}{3} + \binom{4}{4} = \binom{5}{4} $$

$$ 1+1+1+1+1 = 5$$

It seems to work, but what if given $n=5$ and $m=3$?
Then I'm in trouble...

What will be the correct sigma notation for this case?

Regards.

Comment: @graydad, I think the $[x^{2m}](...)$ means the coefficient of $x^{2m}$ in $(...)$.  So in this case, the OP is simply using the binomial theorem.

Comment: I've put $ [x^{2m}] $ just to denote that I'm looking for it's coefficient in $(a+x)^n$

Comment: What is wrong with factoring the LHS so that it it $((1-x)(1+x))^{n}$ and cancelling.  Then you know the LHS and the RHS are the same, and you know the coefficient of $x^{2m}$ in the RHS... so it must be the same on the LHS?

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, it must be the same as on the RHS but I need to show it, so I need to find the coefficient on the LHS as well. To my shame I have problem with factoring. and what to do with negative power of n.. Can you explain a bit how to solve the LHS?

Comment: Why not just say $\frac{(1-x^{2})^{n}}{(1-x)^{n}}=\frac{((1-x)(1+x))^{n}}{(1-x)^{n}}=(1+x)^{n} \frac{(1-x)^{n}}{(1-x)^{n}}=(1+x)^{n}$?

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks a lot!

Comment: Still need help on the second part of the question. Can someone please help on it?

Comment: I don't think I understand what the second question is asking.  Where do the $n$ and $m$ come from?

Comment: @TravisJ $n$ and $m$ coming from the first part, from the binomial-coefficient that was found in it.

Comment: So when I'll plug a numbers, say $n=5$ and $m=2$ the equation should be valid.

Comment: I posted the method for generating your binomial coefficient as a sum of smaller terms.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write $\binom{n}{m}$ as a sum of binomial coefficients, you can do it in the following way (assuming $0\leq m< n$).  We will repeatedly apply Pascal's identity: $\binom{n}{m}=\binom{n-1}{m}+\binom{n-1}{m-1}$.

\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{m} &= \binom{n-1}{m}+\binom{n-1}{m-1} \\
             &= \binom{n-1}{m}+\binom{n-2}{m-1}+\binom{n-2}{m-2} \\
             &= \binom{n-1}{m}+\binom{n-2}{m-1}+\binom{n-3}{m-2}+\binom{n-3}{m-3} \\
             &\vdots \\
             &=\sum_{i=0}^{m}\binom{n-(i+1)}{m-i}
\end{align*}